# bash + how to capture the requated field from variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, environment-variables

we set the variable with the follwing values

```
MY_VAR=" one two three four"
```

how to capture the first value from variable with bash? ( without using echo command )

expected output

one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more appropriate for StackOverflow... in fact it's been asked many times before!

Inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918931/1347519).

```bsh
$ MY_VAR=" one two three four"
$ read -ra MY_VAR <<< "${MY_VAR}"
$ echo ${MY_VAR[0]}
one
$ echo ${MY_VAR[2]}
three
```

Or (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257398/1347519)):

```bsh
$ MY_VAR=" one two three four"
$ MY_VAR=(${MY_VAR// / })
$ echo ${MY_VAR[0]}
one
```

Comment: Other ways to capture expected output `output=$(printf $MY_VAR)` `output=$(cut -d' ' -f2 <<<"$MY_VAR")`

Comment: Both of which invoke external processes.

Comment: I don't have defense for `cut`, but `printf` can be invoked as builtin `output=$(builtin printf $MY_VAR)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo $MY_VAR | awk '{print $1;}'
```

Comment: without to use echo command